# Javascript function embedded in HTML that is embedded in PHP not working properly?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, button

That title is a mouthful...
Hey people! I've been having this bug with a web app project for school that I haven't been able to get passed after trying alternate methods for the past week or so. I'm hoping someone might be able to catch something that I can't...

Okay so here's the code which I believe is the source of the problem:

```
 echo"<div class='RightSidebar'> <button id='AtkBtn' type='button' onclick='attack(".$currentTurn.");'><b>Attack</b></button></a>\n";
```

Here's the Javascript function:

```
function attack(turn)
{
    if(turn == 1 )
        {alert('It is not your turn!!');}
    else
    {
        document.getElementById.("TextLog").innerHTML = "You attack the enemy!";
    }
}
```

(This is the only code in a file named "BattleMethods.js"; the script tags above the opening body tag states we'll be using this file. I can copy that line too if it helps...)
No effects are being passed yet (i.e., the effect on the enemy's health). I want to get this running first and then code that out.

Now with that given information I need the following to happen:

1) Player hits the Attack button within a right sidebar div

2) TextLog div below the battle screen div that shows the enemy reveals current relevant information (i.e: "You attack the enemy!")

3) Client-side variables update appropriately (userHP, currentTurn, etc)

That is all. I can get the variables to update with no problem if I can figure out whats not allowing the function to react when player clicks the Attack button. I had done something similar in the item store and it worked fine. So I'm really at a loss. I hope this is enough information! Any help is much appreciated.

HTML where script lies:

```
echo"<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
echo"<html>\n";
echo"<head>\n";
echo"<title>SlateKeeper -- BATTLEROOM</title>\n";
echo"<meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=0.98; maximum-scale=5;initial-            scale=0.98;user-scalable=no;width=1024'>\n";

echo"<link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href='CSS/battleTowersStyles.css'>\n";
echo"<script language= 'Javascript' type = 'text/javascript' src='Javascript/BattleMethods.js'></script>\n";

echo"<style>\n";

echo"                body {background-color: #3b4870}\n";
echo"</style>\n";

echo"</head>\n";
```

Comment: "*script tags above the opening body tag*" - you mean inside it, or inside the `<head>`? While it shouldn't matter, placing them as children of `<html>` is invalid.

Comment: What is the value of `$currentTurn`? Please post the HTML that the PHP produces.

Comment: if($enemySPD < $yourSPD){$currentTurn=0;}
    else{$currentTurn=1;}

Where $enemySPD is the speed of the enemy from the database (SQL) and $yourSPD is the users. In this case, the enemy's speed was 5 and the user's 10 making the $currentTurn = 0.

Comment: OK, that looks fine (and yes you really should delete that comment and only edit it into the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following changes I've made to this code.It is working properly.
These are the javascript changes.

    `function attack(turn)
    {
    if(turn == 1 )
    {
    alert('It is not your turn!!');
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById('TextLog').innerHTML = "You attack the enemy!";
    }
    }`


PHP CODE IS 
    
    `$turn = 0;
    echo"<div class='RightSidebar'> <button id='AtkBtn' type='button' onclick='attack($turn)'><b>Attack</b></button></a>\n";`

You had made mistake in the line,
`document.getElementById.("TextLog").innerHTML = "You attack the enemy!";`

It should have been

`document.getElementById("TextLog").innerHTML = "You attack the enemy!";`